# Why does adding random numbers not compromise my custom loss?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

This is an extended version of the same question: [Why does adding random numbers not break this custom loss function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70833288/17700571)

Can someone explain to me why these models both get a very good AUC, even though the loss in the second one should be extremely compromised due to adding random numbers? Since the loss functions work correctly I assume it has something to do with how I ensure reproducibility by resetting the seeds or with some theoretical problem I don't understand.

**priv** is an additional input I need for my full custom loss function and not necessary for this example. Also, my full loss function does not work with eager execution so I have to disable it.

```
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-04)

def binary_crossentropy1(y_true, y_pred): 

  bin_cross = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=False)
  bce1 = K.mean(bin_cross(y_true, y_pred))
  return bce1

def binary_crossentropy2(y_true, y_pred): 

  bin_cross = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=False)
  bce2 = K.mean(bin_cross(y_true, y_pred)) + tf.random.normal([], mean=0.0, stddev=10.0)
  return bce2

def reset_random_seeds():
   os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED']=str(1)
   tf.random.set_seed(1)
   np.random.seed(1)
   random.seed(1)

from tensorflow.python.framework.ops import disable_eager_execution
disable_eager_execution()

#model 1

reset_random_seeds()

input1 = keras.Input(shape=(9,))
priv = keras.Input(shape=(1,))
x = layers.Dense(12, activation="relu", kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=123))(input1)
x = layers.Dense(8, activation="relu", kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=123))(x)
output = layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid", kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=123))(x)
model1 = keras.Model(inputs=[input1, priv], outputs=output)

model1.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=binary_crossentropy1)

model1.fit(x=[X_train, priv_train], y=y_train_float, epochs=10, batch_size = 32)

model1_pred = model1.predict([X_test,priv_test])

print(model1_pred)

#model 2

reset_random_seeds()

input1 = keras.Input(shape=(9,))
priv = keras.Input(shape=(1,))
x = layers.Dense(12, activation="relu", kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=123))(input1)
x = layers.Dense(8, activation="relu", kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=123))(x)
output = layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid", kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=123))(x)
model2 = keras.Model(inputs=[input1, priv], outputs=output)

model2.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=binary_crossentropy2)

model2.fit(x=[X_train, priv_train], y=y_train_float, epochs=10, batch_size = 32)

model2_pred = model2.predict([X_test,priv_test])

print(model2_pred)
```

Comment: `from_logits=True` together with `activation="sigmoid"` is not necessary. Use one of them.

Comment: That's right, I corrected it. Unfortunately, it did not influence the outcome.

Comment: The question is if the loss function is really the only possible problem. It is hard to say.

Comment: I actually think that the problem does not lie in the loss functions, they work when used individually. But somehow the model "ignores" the randomly added numbers and I have no clue how that can happen. I can only assume I made some mistake in building or compiling the model but I really can't find it.

Comment: Try replacing `+` in the loss function with `*`.. No difference?

Comment: Great idea! It does change the outcome. Now the AUC for the compromised loss is 0.5 because it always predicts the same class. Any idea why `+` does not work in a loss function or what might be an alternative?

Comment: I think I got it. The mean of the added random numbers is zero. So when we add a lot of them we add zero. With multiplication, this does not happen.

Comment: Thank you for helping :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've been taught that loss controls model training. That's an incomplete story. What really controls model training is the gradients. When you add a random number to the loss, it doesn't affect the gradient.

Imagine a mountain with a slope of 30 degrees, and a ball rolling down the mountain in a certain direction (the path of least resistance).

Now imagine pushing that entire mountain up by 10 feet. The ball still rolls in the same direction.

That's the intuition for you here.

The place that this applies that first comes to mind is the equivalence of KL divergence and crossentropy as a loss, despite being different equations. The difference is just a constant and hence, the two produce the same gradients. This suggests that there's a connections between crossentropy, which comes from Frequentist Maximum Likelihood Estimation, and KL Divergence which is normally more of an information theory concept.

Comment: Thank you for your response and the nice explanation. What I don't understand is how I could make this kind of penalty influence the gradients. I thought it already did because it is inside of the same loss function but if that is not the case how can I change that? By writing my own binary_crossentropy function instead of using the one from Keras? (I'm still starting to get into the theory, sorry if this question does not make sense).

Comment: The first derivative of a constant (even if randomly sampled) is zero, so that's why it doesn't move training. Solution? multiply the random number by a weight or output of the model. Voila.

Comment: I multiplied the added number with one prediction divided by itself so it depends on the output but does not change the function. Unfortunately, it still does not change the outcome. Maybe another theoretical problem I don't get?

Comment: sorry that didn't work. It may be that a random number sampled from a normal distribution "makes the mountain pointier" but still sends the ball in the same direction. If you up the stdev, it's likely you'll eventually overnoise the loss but the failure would likely be gradient explosion, not what you want to see (ball going wrong direction).

Comment: Another idea would be to multiply the predictions by a random number (before the softmax), or, even random feature maps. It's an interesting observation that this model is somewhat robust to noise, and it's something that you might consider studying. Especially with optimizers AdamW, RMSPropr, and Momentum that make attempts to denoise gradients.