# Why does adding random numbers not break this custom loss function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

Can someone explain why adding random numbers to the loss does not affect the predictions of this Keras model? Every time I run it I get a very similar AUC for both models but I would expect the AUC from the second model to be close to 0.5. I use Colab.

Any suggestions why this might be happening?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import keras as keras
from keras import layers
import random
from keras import backend as K
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-04)

#resetting seeds to ensure reproducibility

def reset_random_seeds():
   tf.random.set_seed(1)
   np.random.seed(1)
   random.seed(1)

def get_auc(y_test,y_pred):

  fpr, tpr, threshold = metrics.roc_curve(y_test, y_pred)
  auc = metrics.auc(fpr, tpr)
  return auc

#standard loss function with binary cross-entropy

def binary_crossentropy1(y_true, y_pred): 

  bin_cross = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=False)
  bce1 = K.mean(bin_cross(y_true, y_pred))
  return bce1

#same loss function but with added random numbers

def binary_crossentropy2(y_true, y_pred): 

  bin_cross = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=False)

  bce2 = K.mean(bin_cross(y_true, y_pred))
  penalty = tf.random.normal([], mean=50.0, stddev=100.0)
  bce2 = tf.math.add(bce2, penalty)
  return bce2

#model without randomness

reset_random_seeds()

input1 = keras.Input(shape=(9,))
x = layers.Dense(12, activation="relu", kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=123))(input1)
x = layers.Dense(8, activation="relu", kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=123))(x)
output = layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid", kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=123))(x)
model1 = keras.Model(inputs=input1, outputs=output)


model1.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=binary_crossentropy1, metrics=['accuracy'])

model1.fit(x=X_train, y=y_train, epochs=10, batch_size = 32)

model1_pred = model1.predict(X_test)

#model with randomness

reset_random_seeds()

input1 = keras.Input(shape=(9,))
x = layers.Dense(12, activation="relu", kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=123))(input1)
x = layers.Dense(8, activation="relu", kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=123))(x)
output = layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid", kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=123))(x)
model2 = keras.Model(inputs=input1, outputs=output)


model2.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=binary_crossentropy2, metrics=['accuracy'])

model2.fit(x=X_train, y=y_train, epochs=10, batch_size = 32)

model2_pred = model2.predict(X_test)


print(get_auc(y_test, model1_pred))
print(get_auc(y_test, model2_pred))
```

**Result**

```
0.7228943446346893
0.7231896873302319
```

**What the penalty looks like**

```
penalty =  112.050842
penalty =  139.664017
penalty =  152.505341
penalty =  -37.1483
penalty =  -74.08284
penalty =  155.872528
penalty =  42.7903175
```

Comment: is it possible for you to print out the value of the penalty for each batch as well?

Comment: Added some. Note that I removed the `mean` before the random number generator because it only produces a scalar tensor anyways.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does adding random numbers not compromise my custom loss?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70803497/why-does-adding-random-numbers-not-compromise-my-custom-loss)

Comment: That is actually my question I posted before. I thought it was answered but then I realized that the mean of the distribution should not have an influence because only one random number is added per batch. (Let me know if it is bad style to post a new question instead of changing the old one).

Comment: I don't see what you changed from the last question, except changing the mean of the random numbers to 50 instead of 0. The answer to that question still applies (in contrast, the currently only answer to this question right here is wrong). Adding random numbers to your loss (or constants, or _anything_ that is not dependent on the model parameters in a differentiable manner) does not change the gradients, which are the _only_ thing that matters for model training.

Comment: Okay, I see. If you post this as an answer I'd be happy to mark the question as answered. I am quite new to this and I guess I still have a lack of understanding of how the loss affects the predictions. The problem is I am trying to build a loss function with an additional penalty to binary cross-entropy. If adding anything does not affect the training, then is there no way to add a penalty to the loss?

Comment: Adding stuff to your loss should have no influence whatsoever because any term that is added to the loss function will ultimately vanish in backprop because the derivative is taken, correct?
Same as when you have `m * x + b`, the derivative will not contain `b`, because it is independent from the model variables.
EDIT: Sorry @xdurch0 already gave this answer.

Comment: I guess I can then solve the problem by switching to multiplication instead of summation, right? Please one of you post it as an answer so I can mark it as accepted. You really helped me :)

Comment: I'm assuming this question is an attempt at understanding the issue with this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70813577/what-is-wrong-with-this-custom-keras-loss-function If so -- that is a different story, because there, your additional penalty _is_ affected by the predictions, and thus can in principle influence the model gradients. It's not about adding "anything", but _what_ you are adding. Regarding the linked question -- I will try to remember to take a closer look at that one once I have time and then answer there -- I'm assuming this will help you more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The training is guided by the gradient of the loss with respect to the input.

The random value that you add to the loss in the second model is independent form the input, so it will not contribute to the gradient of the loss during training. When you are running the prediction you are taking the the model output (before the loss function), so that's not affected as well.